# Powershell Remove-Variable cmdlet, do I need to call it at the end of each function/scriptblock?

Tags: powershell, variables, scope, garbage-collection

This is a generic question, no code.
Not sure if I need to remove local variables as I thought it should be done by the Powershell Engine.
I had a script to gather info from WMI and used a lot of local variables. The output was messed up when running multiple times, but it got fixed after I clean up all local variables at the end of function/scriptblock.

Any thoughts/idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Without code and context it's hard to comment. Variables are removed when the powershell host closes or they are redefined. If you're running the code in an editor they could be retained until you restart the editor..

Comment: A code sample would certainly help. In general, you don't need to call `Remove-Variable`. Make sure to initialize variables in all code paths, e. g. don't do something like `if(condition){ $foo = 42 }` if you have not initialized the variable `$foo` before the `if` statement (or set the variable in the `else` branch too). Use `Set-StrictMode` to let PowerShell throw an error if you try to read uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the help. Set-StrickMode is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble do not come from the fact that you do not remove your vars, but by at least from two beginers errors (or done by lazy developpers like me, supposing I'am a developper).

1. we forget to itialize our vars before using them.
2. we do not test every returns of our functions or CmdLets calls.

Once these two things done (code multipled by two at least) you can restart your script without cleaning anything except the processed datas.

For me scripting is most of the time done on a corner of a table even not push in a source repository.

So start scripting and ask yourself fewer questions.

Comment: Keep the good habit from C/C++ is still necessary when using Powershell. I will keep that in mind.